# How to add php code inside link_before inside wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

I want to add this line `<img src="<?php field('text') ?>" alt="" />` inside

```
wp_nav_menu( array $args = array( 'link_before' => 'ADD_CODE_HERE' ));
```

but it doesn't work because link_before is for text.
Is there any way to add this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'link_before' => '<img src="'. field("text") .'" alt="" />' ));
```

If your `field("text")` has proper value then the image will show up.

Comment: there is a simple link in text format to the image. I tried your code and here is the result: <img src alt>

Comment: That's because your field("text") not giving any value. 
Which method did you use to generate this text field? Custom Field?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with wordpress. I use ACF plugin. But it works well outside of the wp_nav_menu.

Comment: Hmmm, now it doesn't work outside too. Strange. I think your code is should be valid. Thank you. I will find the problem and check your code.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I made mistake in functions file.